# Load fonts via URL in nodejs gm library

Tags: javascript, node.js, fonts, imagemagick

I'm using [gm](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) library to add some text on my image. Here is the code:

```
imageMagick(source)
  .fill(fillColor) // font color
  .fontSize(fontSize) // set font size
  .font(font)
  .drawText(x, y, text, gravity) // set x, y and text
  .write(output_file, function(err) { // output the modified image
    if (err) console.log(err); // if error, log it
    else console.log("Image generated"); // log success
  });
```

This works if I load the fonts (in `.font(font)`) from a local file. But if I load the fonts from URL (say from cloudfront) default fonts are being loaded.

The fonts being loaded this way: `/home/user/some/dir/font_name.ttf` - this works. `https://cloud.front.url/font/font_name.ttf` - this does not work.

It might be worth noting that I'm using ImageMagick:

```
var gMagick = require('gm');
var imageMagick = gMagick.subClass({
  imageMagick: true
});
```

Any way to load fonts from URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, ImageMagick does not support loading fonts from URL. The font file has to be saved on local storage.